# What could cause a reverse SSH port forwarding tunnel to not work when initiated but start working exactly at midnight?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I followed [this guide](https://floof.cc/2020/01/05/nextcloud-reverse-proxy-with-autossh/) to forward a port on my VPS (public static IP) to access a Nextcloud installation on a remote server behind a firewall. It worked - sort of. At any point in time, the remote server (with Nextcloud installed) is able to establish a reverse SSH tunnel to the VPS and is therefore accessible locally from the VPS.

Here the custom service that I used:

```
     [Unit]  
 Description=Keep a tunnel to vps open  
 After=network-online.target

[Service]  
 Type=simple 
 User=autossh 
 Restart=always 
 RestartSec=60 
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -R *:13000:127.0.0.1:443 -N -o "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes" -o "ServerAliveInterval 15" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" autossh@[vps_ip] -p 22

[Install]  
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the forwarded port 443 (for https access) is not always accessible externally from a client.

The following, really weird behavior occurs:

1. Let's start at the point when it's all working. The custom service is running, the tunnel is open and all traffic to [vps_ip]:13000 gets correctly forwarded to port 443 on the remote server, and I can access my Nextcloud.
2. Upon a reboot of the VPS, the tunnel is closed and the service from the remote server tries to reconnect without luck.
3. After the VPS is fully booted again, all seems to be working fine again, the service is connected, the tunnel established and no logs or error messages point to anything being wrong. HOWEVER, the port 13000 on the VPS no longer forwards to 443 on the remote server, when accessed externally. The tunnel still works when accessed directly from the shell of the VPS.

This is the response to the following command:

```
sudo service nextcloud-forward status -vvv

nextcloud-forward.service - Keep a tunnel to vps open

     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nextcloud-forward.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-15 23:59:52 CET; 36min ago
   Main PID: 7430 (autossh)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4620)
     Memory: 1.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nextcloud-forward.service
             ├─7430 /usr/lib/autossh/autossh -R *:13000:127.0.0.1:443 -N -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval 15 -o ServerAliveCountMax 3 autossh@[vps_ip] -p 22
             └─7459 /usr/bin/ssh -L 33168:127.0.0.1:33168 -R 33168:127.0.0.1:33169 -R *:13000:127.0.0.1:443 -N -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ServerAliveInterval 15 -o ServerAliveCountMax 3 -p 22 autossh@[vps_ip]

Nov 15 23:59:52 nextcloud systemd[1]: Started Keep a tunnel to vps open.
Nov 15 23:59:52 nextcloud autossh[7430]: starting ssh (count 1)
Nov 15 23:59:52 nextcloud autossh[7430]: ssh child pid is 7459
```

4. No amount of reboots, restarts of services (such as the custom tunnel one or the sshd service), force-killing ssh processes and starting them again, retrying different ports etc. seem to help. No errors, nothing unusual in the logs as far as I can tell.
5. THEN out of the blue I found out, that it suddenly just starts working again on its own exactly at midnight. No configuration changed, no services restarted, nothing. The tunnel just suddenly starts working when accessed externally again.

I've been at this for at least a week and I can't figure out what's going on. I'd appreciate any ideas, please ask questions if something is not clear. I can provide neccessary logs etc..

Thanks in advance!

System Info: Both Machines use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. The VPS is just a cheap rented VPS like any other, the remote server runns in Virtualbox on a Windows 10 LTSC Host.

I tried asking this on Stack Overflow, but got no answers, perhaps someone here can help me?

Comment: When the tunnel isn't working correctly, what happens when you try to connect to the tunnel? Do you get error messages? What do they say? Try modifying your autossh command to run ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output, and see what ssh prints when you're trying to use the tunnel and it's not working correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respone. I just get a timeout in chrome, this is the response to an external wget: failed: Resource temporarily unavailable. I'll do what you suggested and get back.

Comment: So, I ran the reverse tunnel manually with the -vv tag. When running a wget command from the VPS, it works and the ssh log relects that. However, when trying to access it externally, absolutely nothing happens in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Watever the cause of this weird behavior, reinstallung Ubuntu from scratch on the VPS seems to have solved this.